# JAX-RS webservice using @Path("/") at class level fails on TomEE+ 1.5.1

Tags: cxf, jax-rs, java-ee-6, apache-tomee

This simple root resource class fails when running on TomEE+ 1.5.1, return is a 404 error "The requested resource is not available."  It is packaged as a WAR with and empty web.xml file in WEB-INF.

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;


@Path("/")
@Produces({ "text/plain", "text/html", "text/xml", "application/xml", "application/json" })
public class BrokenResource {
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(BrokenResource.class);


    public BrokenResource()
    {
        logger.info("constructed");
    }

    @GET
    @Path("getloggedinguids")
    public Response foo(@Context UriInfo uInfo)
    {
        return Response.ok("\n\n\nrequest URI = " + uInfo.getRequestUri()).build();
    }
}
```

It deploys and I see these lines in the console output:

```
Mar 22, 2013 4:56:16 PM org.apache.openejb.server.rest.RESTService deployPojo
INFO: REST Service: http://localhost:8080/test//*  -> Pojo BrokenResource
```

I have also tried packaging it with a web.xml that declares:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <display-name>Test OpenEJBRest Servlet</display-name>

    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.openejb.server.rest.OpenEJBRestServlet
    </servlet-class>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Same results as with an empty web.xml file.

I also tried changing the class level @Path annotation to @Path("*") and then I get a different response, in the console output I see the following line:

```
WARNING: No root resource matching request path /test/getloggedinguids has been found, Relative Path: /getloggedinguids.
```

Finally... if I change the @Path annotation to something like @Path("/foo") then that works exactly as expected... hitting /test/foo/getloggedinguids returns the request URI..

I've be trying all sorts of variations of servlet mapping versus class level annotations and one thing is consistent... a @Path("/") annotation at the class leve always fails.

I even grabbed an example from the "RESTful Java with JAX-RS book" that uses the @Path("/") at the class level... that also fails.

Is this a bug in the CXF implementation of the JAX-RS standard?  My project requires that I use a stock TomEE+ container so I can't switch to another JAX-RS implementation :-(

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding entries into the web.xml, keep in mind TomEE has native support for JAX-RS if you use the `JAX-RS` or `TomEE+` versions.

Add a class like this and remove your web.xml entries:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;


@ApplicationPath("/")
public class NoteTakerApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return new HashSet<Class<?>>(Arrays.asList(BrokenResource.class, RestExceptionMapper.class, OtherClassesYouMayHave.class));
    }
}
```